# Unable to open h2.jar on mac

Tags: java, jar, h2

I' trying to build an H2 database for my java application, and I think it's working but I can't execute the .jar file to see if it's working or not........ I'm doing this with my friend he has a mac to and it's working well for him, we have the same java version

I've tried by double clicking on the .jar and I've tried to open it with the command line

`java -jar h2-1.3.170.jar` and it showed me that exception

```
IO Exception: "java.net.UnknownHostException: dhcp-10-231-195-255: dhcp-10-231-195-255: nodename nor servname provided, or not known" [90028-170]

    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:273)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.getLocalAddress(NetUtils.java:263)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.updateURL(WebServer.java:325)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.init(WebServer.java:315)
    at org.h2.tools.Server.<init>(Server.java:51)
    at org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer(Server.java:412)
    at org.h2.tools.Console.runTool(Console.java:228)
    at org.h2.tools.Console.main(Console.java:100)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: dhcp-10-231-195-255: dhcp-10-231-195-255: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1438)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.getLocalAddress(NetUtils.java:261)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: dhcp-10-231-195-255: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:866)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1258)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1434)
    ... 7 more
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.message.DbException: IO Exception: "java.net.UnknownHostException: dhcp-10-231-195-255: dhcp-10-231-195-255: nodename nor servname provided, or not known" [90028-170]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:273)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.getLocalAddress(NetUtils.java:263)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServer.getURL(TcpServer.java:193)
    at org.h2.tools.Server.getStatus(Server.java:391)
    at org.h2.tools.Console.printProblem(Console.java:300)
    at org.h2.tools.Console.runTool(Console.java:270)
    at org.h2.tools.Console.main(Console.java:100)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.net.UnknownHostException: dhcp-10-231-195-255: dhcp-10-231-195-255: nodename nor servname provided, or not known" [90028-170]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: dhcp-10-231-195-255: dhcp-10-231-195-255: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1438)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.getLocalAddress(NetUtils.java:261)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: dhcp-10-231-195-255: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:866)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1258)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1434)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Could you check your `/etc/hosts` file? Do you use a VPN or a special firewall? Do you use IPv6 by default and have disabled IPv4?

Comment: No, I just looked into it, and there is nothing like you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

To temporary fix it, edit host files and append your host name to `127.0.0.1` 
loopback address:

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

> 127.0.0.1       localhost YourHostname
>
> 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
>
> ::1             localhost
>
> fe80::1%lo0     localhost
>
> 192.168.1.3     loki

to set it in the first place, use:

> sudo scutil --set HostName YourHostname

Follow this JIRA Link for more informaiton: https://jira.exoplatform.org/browse/KER-203?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Answer (score 2):

If you do a Google search for this exception, you will find [others](http://blog.leon-rosenberg.net/2012/08/oracle-kills-getlocalhost-on-macos-x-in.html) having the same problem. This might be caused by a [bug in Java 7](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7180557).